# parseJSON not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

the $.parseJSON is not working as expected on Ajax call. I think there is something wrong with $.parseJSON. I know I am getting the data but the parsing is not working as expected.

PHP:

```
   if(isset($_POST['getHeaders'])){
        $appInfo = array(app_id =>APP_ID);
         echo json_encode($appInfo);
   }
```

JS:

```
$.post( "dispatcherURl", { 'getHeaders': 'getHeaders'})
.done(function(data) {
      if(data){
        alert(data);
        var appInfo = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(appInfo);
      }

      else{
        alert('no header data found');
      }
});
```

On the first alert I get: x{"app_id":"1234335"}
but the second alert never fires!!!

BTW: the x comes on the alert not user where it's coming from.

Comment: Where's that `x` coming from? Does `parseJSON` throw because of that? Check your error console!

Comment: is that "x" a typo? If you actually have an "x" in front, it's not valid JSON

Comment: that's not a type it comes with x!!!

Comment: Run your PHP code in the browser. What does that look like? Paste that in your question...

Comment: if its not a typo that means you are printing an `x` somewhere above the code you provided.

Comment: How does your PHP not error out when defining that array?  `app_id` is a bareword as the key; that needs to either be quoted or a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... there was something wrong with one of the Php include files.. Thanks much for help guys